# Use nginx location blocks with Shinyproxy

Tags: nginx

I recently successfully deployed a ShinyProxy + app using SSL with nginx and certbot in the following manner:

1. Dockerize ShinyProxy  + app and launch on port `127.0.0.1:5001`.
2. Create Nginx config and `proxy_pass` to `127.0.0.1:5001`.
3. Secure using `certbot`.

This is the successful nginx.conf `location` section:

```
    location / {
                     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                     proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                     proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
    
                     proxy_http_version 1.1;
                     proxy_redirect off;
    
                     proxy_read_timeout  90s;
                     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5001;
           }
```

This nicely redirects me to `https://app.myweb.com/login` as I have set up a `CNAME`. Important to note, {ShinyProxy} redirects to the `login` at the end automatically. On successful login the url redirects to `https://app.myweb.com/app/website`.

What I really struggle with is the following: adding a `location block` or as I understand it, include my `upstream` block into my `downstream` (correct my terms if I am wrong). So, have my url go from `https://app.myweb.com/login` to `https://app.myweb.com/dashboard/login` using the following configuration in nginx:

```
location /dashboard/ { # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD
                     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                     proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                     proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
    
                     proxy_http_version 1.1;
                     proxy_redirect off;
    
                     proxy_read_timeout  90s;
                     proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5001;
           }
```

All that happens is, if I type `https://app.myweb.com/dashboard/` it doesn't go to `https://app.myweb.com/dashboard/login` as I would expect, but redirects back to `https://app.myweb.com/login` which `404`'s.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /dashboard/ { # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD
```

Could you try it like this. It may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your application's base URL to match the URL nginx is configured with.

Comment: Hi @tero-kilkanen, could you perhaps shown some examples? I have set `server_name app.myweb.com` at the top of my `server{}` block if that is what you mean. I have then also set the CNAME to `app.myweb.com`